# Custom Number Format in SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-expression

I am using `SSRS Report` and I need to define a **`Custom Number Format`** for Tablix Textbox.

**For example:**

Convert **`012123456`** To **`012-123456`**.

How can I do this by using custom number format or by using `FORMAT`

Please suggest me!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I have tried below as per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051604/ssrs-custom-number-format), but no success.

```
=Format(Fields!Number.Value,"000-000000")
=Format(Fields!Number.Value,"###-#######")
```

Then I tried something like below and working fine now.

```
=Format(CDbl(Fields!Number.Value),"000-000000")
```

I can use this, `=Format(CDbl(Fields!PA_File_Number.Value),"###-######")` but output would be **`12-123456`** and I want **`012-123456`**.

Here, `CDbl()` is required as my `Number` column datatype is `varchar()`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need change format style

```
"###-######"
```

to

```
"0##-######"
```

"(0). Digit placeholder. Displays a digit or a zero. If the expression has a digit in the position where the zero appears in the format string, display it; otherwise, displays a zero in that position." Additional information about various placeholders you can find on then MSDN page (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fb56f4y(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: Yes that is correct. But if we use `000-000000` then no need to change any format style. It will work fine.

Comment: Yes that's why I have given answer to my own question. have you didn't check?

Answer (score 0):

One Simple way is described below

1. Right click on the textbox
2. Click on properties
3. Click on option 'number'
4. Finally select 'Custom' option under category section, and define your desired format in an expression like given below

> =Format(Fields!FieldName.Value,"Any Format here...")